# Python Mathplotlib wrong image output representation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a sparse matrix that contains non zero values at a regular interval (for instance step of 10) but the graphical representation is broken.

I plotted the sparse matrix to see if regular interval is respected, it is the case. Nonetheless, when I give the matrix to the matplotlib `imshow` function, the output is not correctly rendered. Indeed, the regular interval is not respected (Normally the space between each point must be the same but it is not the case at all) and I do not why because matrix representation is correct.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
heatmap = np.zeros((1000, 1000))
for row in range(100, 900, 10):
    for col in range(100, 900, 10):
        heatmap[row, col] = 1 # normally probabilities there

heatmap = heatmap * 255
m = np.ma.masked_where(heatmap > 0.0, heatmap)
plt.imshow(m,aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: I tried to use the `imshow(...,'aspect='auto')` but nothing changed

Comment: If you resize the plot window, the pattern of points showing changes.  So I suspect that this is caused by your pattern being sub-sampled to show it with the number of pixels available.

Comment: Ho yes I only checked on Pycharm. I just directly run the script and the position of dots changed depending of the window size. So is it possible to directly fix the window size without resizing the window by hand?

Comment: The 1000 array pixels comprise approx. 420 pixels in your image. The probability that a datapoint is shown as pixel is hence 42%. Out of the 80 points you want to show, 35 are shown, which are... 43%. Whether or not you will be able to show every pixel on screen would also depend on your screen. I have 1080pixels in height, so if you want to include the margin with the tick labels it's not going to work on my screen. Or is this about saving the image?

Comment: Ok I understand the problem. Well to save the image with `imsave` no problem with the result. What I would like with `imshow` is to have the representation of the image before saving file. Potentially an interactive view where a user can zoom in/out could solve the problem of representation but I think It is not possible with mathplotlib

Comment: Interactive windows with zoom are perfectly possible with matplotlib, they are standard. So it all depends on what you really want. Think of it like a world map, on which you cannot see the Eiffel tower, but if you zoom in, you can (like in GoogleEarth).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks I will go into that direction since it seems that it is the most suitable approach in my case